# Edit Form for Group with Choice List

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

In my Project I have two Enties: `Group` and `Permission` and those are linked together. I am having trouble in creating the Form for the Group Entity. I am quite new to Symfony, so I might miss something simple here.

I have a »AppReset« Command to initialize the app, in there, the Permissions table is filled with a fixed amount of entries, which look like this (n = 9):

```
 #  |  Name    |  type 
--------------------------------
 1  |  VIEW    |  type1
 2  |  EDIT    |  type1
 …
 n  | MASTER   |  type1
--------------------------------
n+1 | VIEW     |  type2
 …
2n  | MASTER   |  type2
```

---

```
2n+1| VIEW     |  type3
 …
 4n | MASTER   |  type4
```

So each Group can have up to 28 Permissions. Within the Edit Form for a Group, I would like to have a Section called Permissions, which itself should be displayed like that:

```
PERMISSIONS:
    type1:
        checkbox#1 (checked if group has this) VIEW
        checkbox#2 (unchecked if not) EDIT
        …
        checkbox#n MASTER
    type2:
       …
    type4:
        …
        checkbox#4n MASTER
```

Please see the below code that I have so far. There are two primary issues:

1. The Permissions are not saved/updated, I guess it is because they are not `mapped`, or not mapped correctly?
2. How can I create a Section for each Permission type?

Here the code for the Entities:

**Group.php (shortened)**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Group implements RoleInterface

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="app_groups_permissions",
 *      joinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *      },
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
 *      }
 *  )
 */
private $permissions;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->permissions    = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function getPermissions() {
    return $this->permissions;
  }

  /**
   * @param Permission $permission
   */
  public function addPermission(Permission $permission) {
    if($this->permissions->contains($permission)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->permissions->add($permission);

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param Permission $permission
   */
  public function removePermission(Permission $permission) {
    if (!$this->permissions->contains($permission)) {
        return;
    }
    $this->permissions->removeElement($permission);

    return $this;
  }
}
```

**Permission.php (shortened)**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Permission
{
    //»default« primary id field
    //simple string fields (name, mask, type)
}
```

**GroupType.php::buildForm**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {  
$builder
    ->add('name',   TextType::class)
    ->add('permissions', PermissionsType::class, ['groups' => [$builder->getData()]])
     ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPostSubmit'])
     ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
 }
```

**PermissionType.php::buildForm**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   
    foreach($options['groups'] as $group) {
        $name = is_null($group->getId()) ? '0' : $group->getId();

        $builder->add($name, ChoiceType::class, [
            'mapped'        => false,
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'label'         => $group->getName(),
            'choices'       => $this->permissions,
            'choice_value'  => 'id',
            'choice_label'  => 'name',
            'data' => array_reduce($this->permissions,
                function($map, $perm) use($group)
                {
                    if($group->getPermissions()->contains($perm)) $map[] = $perm;
                    return $map;
                },[])

        ]);
    }
}
```